# How to fuzzy search my files content (All of them are plain text) using Python or Ruby tool

Tags: osx, python, ruby, text-search

My OS is MAC OSX

I write tons of plain text files (markdown format)

I want to do fuzzy search under my folder

For example,

If the file contains "stackoverflow"

I want the file can be search by sTackover stack overflow stackoverflowww

Is there any tools or gems or packages recommended on osx, thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a python package called [fuzzywuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) that has a number of tools to aid in this sort of text searching.

Example, (from the web site):

```
>>> choices = ["Atlanta Falcons", "New York Jets", "New York Giants", "Dallas Cowboys"]
>>> process.extract("new york jets", choices, limit=2)
    [('New York Jets', 100), ('New York Giants', 78)]
>>> process.extractOne("cowboys", choices)
    ("Dallas Cowboys", 90)
```

Answer (score 1):

[fuz](https://github.com/Magnushhoie/fuz) is a commandline script written in bash that searches contents of plain text files in a directory.

It relies of [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) (general-purpose command-line fuzzy finder).

Both are MIT-licensed.